# How to get token value of login api in android?

Tags: android, api

My code for LoginActivity is:

```
package com.example.developer.orezmi;
public class LoginScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView txt_account, forgotpassword;
    EditText Email, Password;
    ImageView Logo;
    String email, password;
    Dialog progressDialog, dialog;
    Button btn_login;
    AppController appController;
    AppCompatActivity activity;
    SessionManager sessionManager;
    String loginURL = "http://influence360.in/orezmiapp/index.php/mobile/login";
    String token = "";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);
        activity = LoginScreen.this;
        initUI();

    }

    void initUI() {
        txt_account = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_acount);
        forgotpassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_forgotpassword);
        Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        Logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
        btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
        txt_account.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i1 = new Intent(LoginScreen.this, Signup.class);
                startActivity(i1);

            }
        });
        forgotpassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Login();
               /* Intent i = new Intent(LoginScreen.this, Profile.class);
                startActivity(i);*/
            }
        });
    }


    void getData() {
        try {
//
            String URL = "http://influence360.in/orezmiapp/index.php/mobile/login";
            System.out.println("A URL :- " + URL);
            // Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this,"URL")
            JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
            jsonBody.put("type", "1");
            jsonBody.put("email", "");
            jsonBody.put("password", "");
            jsonBody.put("token", "");
//            jsonBody.put("secondkey", "secondobject");
            final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();

            Log.e("JSON String is :- ", " " + mRequestBody);
            Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, mRequestBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("LOG_VOLLEY", response);
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Profile.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("LOG_VOLLEY", error.toString());
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    return headers;
                }

                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                    try {
                        return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");

                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                        VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                    String responseString = "";
                    if (response != null) {

                        responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);

                        Log.e("Response String : -", " " + responseString);

                    }
                    return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                }
            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplication());
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

            stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void Login() {
        email = Email.getText().toString().trim();
        password = Password.getText().toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Email.setError("Enter useId");
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Password.setError("Enter password");
        } else {
            getData();
        }
    }
}
```

[My Login Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZcEs.jpg)
I didn't get any token value after hitting the api. Please help me regarding this. If you got any solution for this problem. thnks in advance fr your help.
how to get rid of problem of this type? If you have any solution for this problem,please feel free to solve this.

Comment: As per your code, you are planning to send token in request body. It can be anything as per your need. You need to check your API specifications.

Comment: https://ibb.co/bK2BFU...
you can check the specifications from the above screenshots.
After getting token. we got this.
https://ibb.co/gop59p